# Query to update a foreign key row in a table in HeidiSql

Tags: mysql, heidisql

In my heidiSql data base,I have **ringee user table**..In that table i have ringee user id,user name,mobile number,imei code,is delete...Here **ringee user id is primary key**.I have **another table called event table**... Here i have event id,ringee user id,event name,place...Here event id is Primary key and `ringee user id is foreign key...

What is my need is ,i need to update the ringee user id(foreign key) in event table when the ringee user id for that paricular id got changed...
How to do this.What is query for that ..Please help me to find...

This is my event table query

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
    `EVENT_ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `RINGEE_USER_ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `TEXT` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `PLACE` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `EVENT_DATE` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `START_TIME` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `END_TIME` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `IS_DELETE` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `CREATED_DTTM` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `MODIFIED_DTTM` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`EVENT_ID`),
    INDEX `EVENT_ID` (`EVENT_ID`),
    INDEX `FK_EVENT_RINGEE_USER_ID` (`RINGEE_USER_ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_EVENT_RINGEE_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`RINGEE_USER_ID`) REFERENCES `ringee_user` (`RINGEE_USER_ID`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Here i need to update the ringee user id..

Comment: document with `show create table xxxx` for each table in question. Nothing else really matters

Comment: Maybe you should accept previous answers before asking new questions

Comment: in previous they just updated particular value to another another..But here i need to update foreign key.....so i doesn't get any idea from previous question

Answer (score 0):

try this **CASCADE**

```
(`RINGEE_USER_ID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE  ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

ex.

```
CREATE TABLE GROUP(
     group_id INT NOT NULL,
     group_name VARCHAR(50),
     PRIMARY KEY (group_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE USER (
     user_id INT, 
     user_name VARCHAR(50), 
     group_id INT,
     FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES GROUP (group_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: after you try it, check out your other questions and mark Answered (with a Green check mark) those that worked for you. That is how we roll here